# Convert NVARCHAR to DATETIME and select distinct Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(convert(varchar(max),OrderCreatedDate)) from webshop
```

The above sql query is producing this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The value in the database is NVARCHAR and in the following format: DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00 AM (/PM)

I would like to select the unique values for the year only!

thanks for any help

Comment: Why are people apparently so reluctant to use proper `date[time]` datatypes?

Comment: Why cant  you have timestamp for such fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this sort of issues, date should be saved in DateTime type field Not in a string field.

`Year()` function parameter is a `DateTime type` *not* a `String`. So you should make sure that the string you are passing is convertible to a DateTime type. In this case you could trim out the time part with `Left() function` and use `103` *style* as below.

**[Fiddle demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/10286)**

```
--Example
declare @val nvarchar(50) = '28/10/2013 11:25:45 AM (/PM)'
select year(convert(date,left(@val,10),103)) myYear

--Applying to your query
SELECT DISTINCT Year(Convert(Date,Left(OrderCreatedDate,10),103)) FROM Webshop
```

**UPDATE:**
If you are getting errors, it could be due to your date format. i.e. Format of the string you have saved may not be as you have described (`DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00 AM (/PM)`) in the question.

Please check with `ISDATE()` function before converting to date and identify which records are causing the problem and correct them.

Try this query to get all of them with invalid strings. Following query will return 0 for values with invalid formatting.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN IsDate(eft(OrderCreatedDate,10))=1 THEN  
                      Year(Convert(Date,Left(OrderCreatedDate,10),103)) 
                ELSE 0 END as myDate,
                OrderCreatedDate
FROM Webshop
```

Or you could get only the records which are causing the problem as;

```
SELECT OrderCreatedDate
FROM Webshop 
WHERE IsDate(Left(OrderCreatedDate,10)) = 0
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and detail! I have tried the query and i get this error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct year(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, columnName,105)))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i now get this error 'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.' any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Convert(datetime,OrderCreatedDate,103)) from webshop
```

`DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00 AM (/PM)` is the British format. See [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I do want to keep the british format, thanks for your suggestion however, with that i get this error 'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Comment: This error is a result of probably bad data. I guess not all of your data is in the correct dd/mm/yyyy format.